# VB Deleting in the AppData folder

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make it so when this is used in anyone's PC, it uses %userprofile% instead of C:\users\Gavin to find a folder / delete a folder.. How do I go about doing so?

````
        If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to clear your cache?", "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            If (My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\Users\Gavin\Appdata\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\")) Then
                If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\Users\Gavin\Appdata\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\browser\") Then
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory("C:\Users\Gavin\Appdata\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\browser\", DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)
                End If
                If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\Users\Gavin\AppData\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\servers\") Then
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory("C:\Users\Gavin\AppData\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\servers\", DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)
                End If
                If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\Users\Gavin\Appdata\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\db\") Then
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory("C:\Users\Gavin\Appdata\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\db\", DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)
                End If
                If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\Users\Gavin\AppData\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\ipfs_data\") Then
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory("C:\Users\Gavin\Appdata\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\ipfs_data\", DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)
                End If
                If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\Users\Gavin\Appdata\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\priv\") Then
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory("C:\Users\Gavin\Appdata\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\priv\", DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)
                End If
                If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\Users\Gavin\Appdata\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\subprocess\") Then
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory("C:\Users\Gavin\Appdata\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\subprocess\", DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)
                End If
                If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\Users\Gavin\Appdata\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\unconfirmed") Then
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory("C:\Users\Gavin\Appdata\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\unconfirmed\", DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)
                End If
                My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Users\Gavin\Appdata\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\crashometry")
                My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Users\Gavin\Appdata\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache\launcher_skip_mtl2")
                MsgBox("Cache Deleted!")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub```
````

Comment: Look at the `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories` object and/or the `Environment.GetFolderPath` method to get standard folder paths. You should get the base folder once and assign it to a variable. You can then use `Path.Combine` or `My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath` to create the common parent folder path, then the same again for each subfolder. Always remain DRY, i.e. "Don't Repeat Yourself". In this case, that means don't keep repeating the same partial path.

Comment: I am very fresh to VB, so I am trying to fully understand this. I kinda get it, Just not sure what the code should fully look like.I appreciate the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

Import `System.Environment` and use `SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`e.g.

```
Dim appData As String = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```